# Is there a elegant c++ API to Hadoop?

Tags: c++, hadoop

Is there a way to submit Map/Reduce job to Hadoop from C or C++?

Something like this but in C++ (this is java code):

```
    Configuration config = new Configuration();

    JobConf job = new JobConf(config);
    job.setJarByClass(MyFirstJob.class);
    job.setJobName("My first job");

    FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, new Path(args[0));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

    job.setMapperClass(MyFirstJob.MyFirstMapper.class);
    job.setReducerClass(MyFirstJob.MyFirstReducer.class);

    JobClient.runJob(job);
```

Thanks.

Comment: any good reason to use c or c++?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google released an open-source framework called [MR4C](http://google-opensource.blogspot.fr/2015/02/mapreduce-for-c-run-native-code-in.html) to run C or C++ code on Hadoop.

Answer (score 1):

you can make use of configuration xml and execute the job for more information on how to execute the job from C++ refer 
[Running C++ Programs on Hadoop](http://cs.smith.edu/dftwiki/index.php/Hadoop_Tutorial_2.2_--_Running_C++_Programs_on_Hadoop) 
or
[C/C++ MapReduce Code & build](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/C++WordCount#Execute)

Comment: Thanks for answer. Just, I am looking for a way to submit job from c++, I don't need mapper and reducer to be in c++.